# how to insert 3d font in corona?

Tags: coronasdk

In my application i have to insert 3d font.i have to set different color for each font.using strips.please give some idea.how to give different shaped color for same font.

`myText = display.newText( "corona", 0, 0, "Harrowprint", 22 )`

Answer (score 1):

```
myText:setTextColor(Rvalue,Gvalue,Bvalue)
```

there's no such thing as 3D font rendering in Corona - the TTF font file is what defines what is displayed